# Laravel geo with Torann\GeoIP

Tags: php, laravel, geoip

I try to use [GeoIP](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip) on Laravel 5.5 and I have problem to get it work.

### What I want

1. I want get users **ISO_CODE** on ***visiting any page in my website***. So I can use it in my chart as visitors country location.

### Issues

1. I can't get `iso_code` on my method (provided below)
2. How can I make it to get data in all my website and not provided static urls?

#### Codes

My method using [Charts](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts)

```
//Header
use GeoIP as GeoIP;

class ChartController extends Controller
{
//.....

//Method
public function index()
    {
      //rest of my codes
      $data = geoip()->getLocation();
      $chart3 = Charts::create('geo', 'highcharts')
             ->title('My nice chart')
             ->elementLabel('My nice label')
             ->labels($data->pluck('iso_code'))
             ->dimensions(1000,500)
             ->responsive(true);
        return view('admin.charts.index', compact('chart3'));
      }
.....
}
```

> Here is default code of charts package to use Geo chart

```
Charts::create('geo', 'highcharts')
    ->title('My nice chart')
    ->elementLabel('My nice label')
    ->labels(['ES', 'FR', 'RU'])
    ->colors(['#C5CAE9', '#283593'])
    ->values([5,10,20])
    ->dimensions(1000,500)
    ->responsive(false);
```

**Error I get:**

> Call to undefined method Torann\GeoIP\Location::pluck()

Any idea how can I achieve what I need?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1: I can't get iso_code on my method (provided below)**

The `geoip()->getLocation()` returns you a `Torann\GeoIP\Location` object, and it's not Laravel Collection, hence you cannot use `pluck`.

Change this line:

```
    ....
    ->labels($data->pluck('iso_code'))
    ....
```

Into this instead:

```
    ....
    ->labels($data->iso_code)
    ....
```

The `Location` class implemented the magic method `__get` so you can just access the attributes of a location by just referring to it like reading the properties of the location object.

Check out the [source code of class `Location`](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip/blob/ed3965a561d98894b27b592cc97c3e4d77cd197c/src/Location.php).

---

**Question 2: How can I make it to get data in all my website and not provided static urls?**

One way to get the information you need, is to create a separate `Service` class in your project, and then include it in the controllers that you need the iso_code.

Comment: Hi, for solution 1 i get error of  `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` but i'm able to get what I'm looking for with this `$data = array('geo' => geoip()->getLocation());` + `->labels($data = array_pluck($data, 'iso_code'))` but my problem is how to get `values` ? and for solution 2: can you walk me through?

Comment: Ah sorry I never use Charts before. I assume the `labels` is expecting an array, hence you will need to supply like `labels(['key' => $data->iso_code])`, I assume

Comment: so i use your way and change labels only or my way and use your labels method?